# HOW to Update MySQL SET value WHERE some column content LIKE another table column content

Tags: mysql, insert-update, sql-like

I have one table with 
City Name Table (citytable)

```
idcity  |   cityname     |  statename  |    codenumber
   1    |   Los Angeles  |   state2    |     ...
   2    |   New York     |   state3    |     ...
   3    |   New Jersey   |   state3    |     ...
```

Code Number City Table (codetable)

```
  id |  city     | codenumber
   1 |  angeles  |   031
   2 |  york     |   064
   3 |  jersey   |   075
```

How to `SET or INSERT or UPDATE data 'codenumber' FROM 'codetable' fields INTO 'codenumber' column FROM citytable WHERE 'city' FROM codetable LIKE '%cityname%' FROM 'citytable'`?
Thanks for your help advance.

Comment: But How use it in PHP code?

Comment: I know how use common syntax MySQL "UPDATE SET value" in PHP. But What I want is when use this in nested Loop PHP code in professional code. Example create code in several step. 1st select data (WHERE statement) then Updating data when there is matching data in first step.

Comment: But there's any result(codenumber)is null (when joining citytable with citytable coz any city without areacode). I want make Looping Code (PHP) to checking data (not null) and then updating any record or print them in looping statement again to make option in combobox to replace codenumber in input text(html) for phone number(areacode) for form registration using Javascript code

Answer (score 2):

use `UPDATE with join`

```
UPDATE  cityTable a
        INNER JOIN codeTable b
            ON a.ID = b.ID
SET     a.codeNumber = b.codeNumber
```

but I suspect here that `ID` are `AUTO_INCREMENT`ed column, if so,

```
UPDATE  cityTable a
        INNER JOIN codeTable b
            ON a.cityName LIKE CONCAT('%', b.city,'%')
SET     a.codeNumber = b.codeNumber
```

Comment: Hi, I see you're new to SO. If you feel an answer solved the problem, please mark it as 'accepted' by clicking the white check mark (*around 15mins to an hour later*). This helps keep the focus on older SO questions which still don't have answers. [*How does accepting an answer work?*](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Comment: here are some link: [PHP MySQL Update (*w3schools*)](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_update.asp), [Updating MySQL via PHP](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlupdate.php) there many sources you can find on the internet `:D`

Comment: I know how use common syntax MySQL "UPDATE SET value" in PHP. But What I want is when use this in nested Loop PHP code in professional code. Example create code in several step. 1st select data (WHERE statement) then Updating data when there is matching data in first step.

Answer (score 0):

@JW and I arrived at the following more or less simultaneously, but JW had the edge on time!

```
UPDATE citytable a
INNER JOIN codetable b ON  a.cityname LIKE CONCAT('%',b.city,'%')
SET a.codenumber = b.codenumber
```

---

Update after Morgan asked for a php example of doing this in a SELECT followed by loop with UPDATE.

```
<?php
#Fill out the four variables below.
#
#This is just an example!
#If you are going to use this for real, you want to put the top
#4 variables in a separate file and include that file into this
#file via phps include directive.  That separate file needs
#to be in a tightly security controlled directory, because
#your database password is in the file.
#
#For security reasons, the variables below must not come from
#user supplied data (from a POST or GET or the SESSION variables).
#
```

```php
$dbName = '';
$hostName = '';
$username = '';
$password = '';


$dbh = new PDO("mysql:dbname=$dbName;host=$hostName",
    $username, $password);
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO_ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO_ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$sqlSelect = "
    SELECT cityname, codenumber
    FROM city a
    INNER JOIN codetable b ON 
        a.cityname LIKE CONCAT('%',b.city,'%');";
$sqlUpdate = "
    UPDATE citytable SET codenumber = ? WHERE cityname = ?";
$rows = $dbh->query($sqlSelect)->fetchAll();
$sth = $dbh->prepare($sqlUpdate);
foreach($rows as $row) {
    $codeNumber = $row['codenumber'];
    $cityName = $row['cityname'];
    $sth->execute(array($codeNumber,$cityName));

}
```

Comment: And it won't perform super well if the table involved are large because of the rather non-optimal join.  But if you need to do this once or occasionally, it'll work.

Comment: Also, you wrap a.cityname in LOWER(), as also b.city, if your tables do not have a case insensitive collation:  `UPDATE citytable a
    INNER JOIN codetable b ON 
        LOWER(a.cityname) LIKE CONCAT('%',LOWER(b.city),'%')
    SET a.codenumber = b.codenumber;";`

Comment: I've updated the code example because you were asking about how to do the SELECT first and then call UPDATE in a loop. Take a look!

Comment: Yes I usualy uses that. But there's any result(codenumber)is null (when joining citytable with citytable coz any city without areacode). I want make Looping Code (PHP) to checking data (not null) and then updating any record or print them in looping statement again to make option in combobox to replace codenumber in input text(html) for phone number(areacode) for form registration using Javascript code.

Comment: Did you see my updated example with looping.  I think you should be able to take that and add your null check?